# Use multiple LTE mobile 3g/4g modems for multi-WAN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, modem, pfsense

Sorry if this sounds silly, but I have a bunch of USB wifi LTE mobile modems for a few providers, and I have an HP T620 thin client lying around with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed.
I was wondering if there was some means to configure the Ubuntu (or maybe pfsense, or VyOS, or  any other firewall software) to use the LTE modems in some kind of multi-wan arrangement?
If this is possible, would I be needing anything else (say a USB switch) to make this happen?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: This is doable but pretty hard.  It also depends very much on the modems you have. (At least under Ubuntu).  It also requires policy based routing.  As long as you can plug them all in to the hcomputer at once you don't need a USB switch.

Comment: Im not sure I have enough ports :-) but will the switch work?

Comment: The modems appear to be a `VIDA M2 LTE router`, a `D-link DWR-832M`, and something called an `SM-LT200+ (4G LTE MIFI)`. Each with their provider signage everywhere inside (UI) and outside (on the body)

Comment: None of the routers you mentioned appear to be USB modems.   (difficult to know for sure because there is limited info on them online.).  Getting this to work is likely not worth the effort - as you will need to power them all, then get your pc to act as an AP client for each modem, then handle the source routing.  There is a dearth of information on step 2, if its even possible (I did manage to get my wifi card to act as a client and server once upon a time, so it may not be impossible)

Comment: Thanks. I guess its smarter to replace them with devices that have ethernet ports and to queue them up on a regular switch.
Hopefully power backup won't be an issue :-) The USB modems are helpful in an region with constant power cuts like mine